# Reading CSV, adding column with random generated password, Python

Tags: python, csv

First let me explain what I want to do:

I want to read a CSV file with usernames. Then, I want to give every user a random generated password in the column next to the username.

When this is done, I want to extract each line (username and password) to a new document with the username as title.

This is my code so far;

```
    #AutogeneratePassword
import csv
import string
import random
def id_generator(size=8, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):



    with open('/home/hoss/usernames.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
        with open('/home/hoss/usernameandpassword.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
            reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

            all = []
            row = next(reader)
            row.append(id_generator)
            all.append(row)

            for row in reader:
                row.append(row[0])
                all.append(row)

            writer.writerows(all)
```

When I run the code I get no errors, but it does not append any passwords to my CSV-file.

EDIT:

So now, I want the script to also check for duplicates before adding password. This is my code so far;

```
    # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import csv
import string
import random
import sys
import time
import os

os.system('clear')

print ("CSV-password generator for usernames")

print ("First, cleaning sourcefile for duplicates")

with open('UsernamesRawfile.csv') as csvdirtyinput:
    with open('UsernamesCleanfile.csv') as csvcleanoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvcleanoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvdirtyinput)

        all = []

        for row in reader:
            if row[0] not in all:
                writer.writerow(row)
                usernames.add( row[0] )


print ("Success, file cleaned")

length = input("Password length?")

def id_generator(size=length, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

with open('UsernamesCleanfile.csv', 'r') as csvinput:                                           
    with open('MasterlistUserPass.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:                                          
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')                                         
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []                                                                                    

        for row in reader: 
            row.append(id_generator())                                                              
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)



print ("")
print ("Passwords generated")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AutoPassCSV2.py", line 24, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
IOError: File not open for writing
```

Comment: There is no code execution apart from the function definition. It just defines the function and thats it. Also, there is no code for random password generation.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work fine -

```
import csv
import string
import random


def id_generator(size=8, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

with open('usernames.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
    with open('usernameandpassword.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []

        for row in reader:
            row.append(id_generator())
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```